# Android textview center letter

Tags: android, textview

Hi i have a Textview which always shows only one word.

Now i need to always to center the second letter. Here is what is have:

```
String Word = "word";
int center = 2;
float measureText = textViewText.getPaint().measureText(word, 0, word.length()) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float measureBeforeCenter = textViewText.getPaint().measureText(word, 0, center) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float measureCenter = textViewText.getPaint().measureText(word, center, center + 1) / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
textViewText.setPadding((int) (measureText / 2 - measureBeforeCenter - measureCenter / 2), 0, 0, 0);
```

its nearly what i want, but the letter still jumps left and right from the center

Comment: can you provide some more info. You need to center only second letter? What about other letters?

Comment: the other letters are regardless. Later i'll center other letters too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a LinearLayout with 3 TextViews?
For example:
[[A][B][C]]
A, B, C are the textviews, where B is wrap_content layout_width, and A and C are set the same width.
Much easier than deal with than measure and paint.

```
<LinearLayout       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_A"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_B"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_C"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```